# Google old GCM vs. Google New GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

i'm developing a news application and i'm confused between using the old GCM and the new GoogleCloudMessaging, they said GCM is deprecated, but it runs well when you get the gcm.jar and compile it in your app.

So my question: is it safe to use the old deprecated GCM method ? or will it be cancelled be Google in the future and won't be able to function any more ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcm.jar` is the old client library used for registration to GCM and receiving GCM messages in the app. It is deprecated, and therefore you are advised not to use it.

Since it's deprecated, it's more likely to have more problems and work in less devices than the `GoogleCloudMessaging` class of the Google Play Services library.

As with any deprecated feature, at some point in the future it may be cancelled, and it's probably better to stop using it long before that time arrives.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide a detailed step-by-step tutorial for the new GoogleCloudMessaging method ?

Comment: @FadiObaji You can take the [Client Demo App](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Many functions that were earlier a part of the AOSP have been gradually shifted to the Google Play Services library (which is proprietary, *not* open-source). I remember the days when the [old location API](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) was a part of AOSP. Wait, that one still is, though ...

If you would like to understand what this is all about, a good starting point would be [this article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/neither-microsoft-nokia-nor-anyone-else-should-fork-android-its-unforkable/), as well [Dianne Hackborn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236398/hackbod) detailed [comment](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/neither-microsoft-nokia-nor-anyone-else-should-fork-android-its-unforkable/?comments=1&post=26199423) on the same. All we devs hear is that the new APIs' are faster and more efficient than the older ones.

In any case you are advised to move to the new APIs' as the older ones will indeed be discontinued anyday.